# Correct application of pd.rolling

Tags: python, pandas

For a time now I have found the usage of pd.rolling a bit strange.

I previously used `pd.rolling_mean` but I think that's deprecated.

Now I am using: `df.A.rolling(window=[0.1, ...], win_type='boxcar')`, so I want a custom window.

In my understanding, which is also shown in the result, if I pass a custom window window type is not needed - but I get an error in that case saying that window needs to be an integer. But, as I said, I just expect win_type to have an influence if I pass a window size instead of an array. Am I wrong?
Further, now I want to use that on groupby - but I just cant get it to run with a custom array.

Example: Writing

```
df.groupby('B').A.rolling(window=[0.1, ...], win_type='boxcar')
```

again gives me the error:

> Window must be an integer.

Could you help me?

So in general I want to group my dataframe by some column (lets say B), and then apply a filter to some other column (lets say A). For the filter I need custom weights [a_1, ..., a_n], s.t. each value x_t = x_{t-1} * a_n + ... + x_{t-n} * a_1.

Example what I want with window [0.5, 0.5]:

```
B  A  Output
0  0  nan
0  1  0.5
0  2  1.5
1  4  nan
1  6  5
```

Comment: pandas version is 0.19.2 btw

Comment: Maybe you want to give an example of your dataframe structure, so people can give a less generic answer? And I assume, you have read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), saying that window has to be an integer or an offset string. The latter is imho only valid for datetimelike indexes.

Comment: Ok, not really sure what I can generalize, but I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: No problem, and ok, I added one. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe it's me. For me a rolling window is the number of indices taken into account for calculation (except for datetime columns). So I don't understand, what window[0.5, 0.5] even means. For the ungrouped example it would be `df["Output"] = df.A.rolling(2).mean()`. But maybe the pandas cracks show up any time soon here to help you.

Comment: Or is your `window[0.5, 0.5]` the desired weighting in your calculation? Weighting is given by `win_type`, i.e. the [window type defines your weighting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#window-functions).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want - sorry about the confusion. As I see it, with win_type I can only take predefined weight structures - e.g. triang or gaussian. So how can I take my arbitrary custom weights?